# Symfony2 Basic Authentication. Token not set

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine, token

Good morning everyone. I am playing with Symfony2 for a little and I have implemented the Basic Authentication that the documentation says.

I can log in but in the debug bar it is said "You are not authenticated".

When I try to retrieve the token, I get NULL, so, I cannot get the user, username or whatever I want.

I have read tons of posts and I cannot find any clue why it is going that way.

Any solution possible?

**login form**

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">User:</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="_password" /> <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

**loginAction**

```
public function loginAction()
{

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();


    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
    {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }



    return $this->render('JillFBAdminBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

**security.yml**

```
providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: JillFBSiteBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    admin_area:
        provider: administrators
        security: true
        anonymous: false
        pattern: ^/admin/
        form_login:
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
            target: /home



access_control:
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER}
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
```

**tokens**

```
5123898f6f3d2   192.168.1.83    GET     http://192.168.1.83:88/Jill/app_dev.php/admin/              Tue, 19 Feb 2013 15:17:51 +0100
5123898f07be5   192.168.1.83    POST    http://192.168.1.83:88/Jill/app_dev.php/admin/login_check   Tue, 19 Feb 2013 15:17:51 +0100
```

Comment: The code is pasted, thanks for viewing :)

Comment: the firewall isn't include ^/user path

Comment: The user section is not implemented for the moment. I am just using the *admin*.

Comment: can you post the log file?

Comment: Edited the question. I am getting a different token after the system redirect.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm currently struggling with the same one...